# Выдает NaN вместо числа

Tags: javascript, функции, nan

Программа должна при нажатии кнопки брать число, прибавлять к нему единицу и выводить результат.
Но выводит NaN. Помогите решить!

Код HTML:

```
<span id="num">0</span>
<button onclick="plus()">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Код JS:

```
function plus() {
    let num, result
    num = document.getElementById('num')
    num = parseInt(num)
    result = 'num' + 1
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = result
}
```

Comment: `result = num + 1`

Comment: лишние кавычки в строке `result = 'num' + 1`

Comment: отсутствие кавычек не поможет, в переменной num хранится объект span, а не его содержимое

Comment: Вы в parseInt запихнули объект Node. Что бы ожидаете на выходе?

Answer (score 2):

`num = document.getElementById('num')`

Здесь в переменную `num` присваивается ссылка на объект HTML-элемента с id="num". Вы пытаетесь превратить объект в число, оттуда выходит NaN. Если нужна строка, написанная внутри элемента, нужно взять непосредственно её, через свойство `textContent`

`result = 'num' + 1` ?! Всё, что пишется в кавычках - это строка. Оно не имеет никакого отношения к переменной `num`. А в переменную `result` присваивается строка `'num1'`

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("num");
  let num = parseInt( elem.textContent );
  
  elem.textContent = num + 1;
});
```

```html
<span id="num">0</span>
<button id="btn">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Вся подобная элементарщина хорошо описана тут → http://learn.javascript.ru/

P.s. В идеале, HTML нужно использовать только для отображения данных, а не хранения. Хранить такие числа следует в переменных / массивах / объектах.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function plus() {
    let num = document.getElementById('num');
    num.innerText ++;
}
```

```html
<span id="num">0</span>
<button onclick="plus()">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обернул ваш код в еще 1 блок родителя, для удобства навигации внутри, сейчас 1 кодом сможете проставлять в любом материале нужное количество.

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('.basket button');
if (el.length > 0) {
   for (let btn of el) {
        btn.onclick = function (e) {
              let i = e.target.previousElementSibling;
              i.innerText = parseInt(i.innerText)+1;
        }
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="basket">
  <span>0</span>
  <button>Добавить в корзину</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, пордон, спутал

Comment: проверка вообще лишнее действие, если массив пустой то цикл и так пропустится

Comment: Малоли у ТС там еще какой то код будет, отправка Аякс может быть, поэтому оставил, да и изменения кол тоже вывел в переменную

Comment: если отправка аякс будет, то она вероятно будет внутри обработчика события нажатия кнопки, а обработчик просто не установится, если элементов не найдётся

Comment: Я это как пример привел, а так кто знает, что там у ТС  будет, может вообще не чего ) А проверка не мешает.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="num">0</span>
<button onclick="plus()">Добавить в корзину</button>

<script>
function plus() {
    let num, result;
    num = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;
    num = parseInt(num);
    result = num + 1;
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = result;
}

</script>
```

Comment: ответ на троечку тут минимум два косяка. два раза подряд ищет элемент вместо того чтобы сохранить в переменной.

Comment: innerHTML зачем? вам не нужно разбирать обновлённое значение как DOMString лучше использовать innerText

Comment: Задача была поставлена, что не суммирует, вот и исправил ошибку, которую пропустил. Если уж смотреть в оптимизации, то можно многое сделать )